# Configure an Azure VM for Dynamic DNS for Cloud Services

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, virtual-machines, azure

I am trying to setup an Azure VM with proper DNS to allow multiple cloud services to communicate across cloud service boundaries.

As I understand it, I need to provide my own DNS server.  I do not have any on-premise infrastructure, so I am trying to configure an Azure VM to act as my DNS.

This SO question - [Azure: How to connect one cloud service with other in one virtual network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858926/azure-how-to-connect-one-cloud-service-with-other-in-one-virtual-network) - is very similar to my setup.

The [Name Resolution (DNS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156088.aspx) from MSDN describes my particular case:

> Name resolution between virtual machines and role instances located in the same virtual network, but different cloud services

Here is what I have done:

1. Created Azure Virtual Network and declared subnets for each of my cloud services.
2. Created an Azure VM (Windows 2012 R2) with DNS enabled
3. RDP to the VM and enabled the DNS role and installed features
4. Added the appropriate NetworkConfiguration xml section to each of my cloud services .csfg files
5. Re-deployed my cloud services

I have verified that I setup the virtual network and networkconfiguration properly because my cloud service hosts are able to communicate with each other if I use the internal ips. However, name resolution doesn't appear to be working, and it doesn't appear that my cloud service roles can communicate with my DNS server.

How do I configure my VM so that my different cloud services roles register themselves with my DNS server?

EDIT:

I think I am 1 step closer to getting this to work.  The cloud services that I was using are in an old affinity group which is not supported by VMs, so I was unable to add my VM into my virtual network.  I created a new VNET in a new affinity group with my VM added into it.  However, I still don't know how to configure the Azure VM's DNS server so that the cloud services register themselves for name resolution.  Also, an added bonus guaranteed to get a +1 would be to explain if it is possible to register a DNS entry for the VIP for an internal endpoint of my cloud services so we can get load balancing.

Comment: To clarify your 'Step 1': Did you create seperate Virtual Networks or just different subnets for each cloud service? Also, is your DNS server added to your VN DNS server list? http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn275925.aspx

Comment: @Byron I created 1 Virtual Network and during the wizard created 3 subnets, A, B, and C for each cloud service.  And yes, I did add my VM DNS server to the virtual network as a DNS server.

Comment: Looking for something similar to this as well.  This article helps show how to set everything up.  http://www.ytechie.com/2013/06/setting-up-a-dns-server-in-azure-iaasvms/
Not sure about the auto register besides having a powershell script, maybe something that runs on cloud service startup?
I believe the DNS server handles the load balancing so you'd have to find one that support that.  In the article it talks about DNS suffix's, which might be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This no longer seems to be an issues or need.  Or at least it won't be when [Internal Load Balancing (ILB) in Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/20/internal-load-balancing/) comes out of preview and is generally available.